# submit sitecore field in form

Tags: sitecore, contact-form

wondered if it was possible to take a sitecore field (for instance a email address on a profile page) and then use this field as the email address to submit it to. I have a contact form working and a profile page. Basically instead of a mailto I want to have that email address as the address the form gets submited to, i.e. mask the persons email address on the profile. Can I simply call the field in the MailMsg or more to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Web Forms for Marketers](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Resources/Sitecore%206/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers%20Module.aspx) (WFFM )to create a front-end form and have it submit an email to anyone. One of the features of the email designer in WFFM is designing an email template with hooks that pull in dynamic fields from the input form. For example, if your form has two fields, **Name** and **Email**, you can send an email to that email address and use the provided name in your email.

Comment: ah sounds good! But won't allow me access, I have a free sitecore account, do I need something special?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot access the WFFM page on the SDN?

Comment: Are you a Sitecore-certified developer? If not, you may not have access to that module. You can [contact your local Sitecore sales rep](http://www.sitecore.net/Company/Contact.aspx) to give you access to it.

Comment: no, not certified, the company I work for has a sitecore licence, would there be account attached to that which would give me access or do I need to go through my reseller to get it?

Comment: I would contact your Sitecore rep and explain you are the license holder (you may need to verify that to them somehow).

Answer (score -1):

You can use .NET's SMTPClient to send email messages. 
http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/2.4.aspx

I hope this answers your question.